# Limit CPU load or set process prority

Tags: php, cpu

It's not the first time I get a too much cpu load warning from my hosting. The code is just some random php script with mysql queries, nothing fancy. (THe tables are nothing extraordinary, a few hundred lines maximum and I always limit them if requested.

I don't mind if it runs for 0.15 second instead of 0.05, so is there a way I can control process priority or limit cpu load?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If this is a dameon or program that runs for long time add [`sleep()`](http://php.net/sleep)/[`usleep()`](http://php.net/usleep). **A small sleep will reduce your CPU usage dramatically**.

Following code will consume a lot of cpu

```
while(...){
//do stuff
}
```

Because you are not giving room for CPU to do other task here. change it to

```
while(...){
   //do stuff
    sleep(1);
}
```

This will greatly decrease your CPU usage. **1 second for CPU is a lot of time to do other task**.

To sleep that extra `0.1` second (`0.15 - 0.05`) use usleep().

```
usleep(100000);
```

Comment: Acually, it will not reduce usage, as it will remain the same. But will pervent process from spiking to 100% CPU usage for whole duration of a script. Which will not block other tasks that should be executed faster.

Comment: So smart and so useful. Thank you very much. Just what I needed

Answer (score 6):

In principle, on Unixish system (Linux, BSD, etc.), you could use the [`proc_nice()`](http://php.net/proc_nice) function to change the process priority, like this:

```
proc_nice( 20 );  // now this process has very low priority
```

However, there are a couple of major caveats here that make it less useful in practice:

- Until PHP 7.2.0 it wasn't supported on Windows at all.
- You're only allowed to increase the niceness, not to decrease it (not even back to its original value).
- The niceness persists until the PHP process exits, which could be a problem if you're running PHP as a FastCGI process, or, even worse, as a webserver extension.
- Because of the above issues, `proc_nice()` might be disabled for security reasons even on systems that could technically support it.

---

What you could try to do, if your webhost allows it, is to [start a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process) for the long-running task, so that your webserver can get back to serving requests while it's running.  You can even use the [`nice`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) shell command to lower the priority of the background process, like this:

```
exec( "nice nohup php -f slow_script.php < /dev/null > output.txt 2>&1 &" );
```

Once the slow script has finished, you can get its output by downloading `output.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! I'd mark this as useful, but I don't have enough rep yet :)

Comment: Actually, my first suggestion wasn't _that_ useful, as I noted, but I just added a possibly more useful one -- see above. :)

Comment: Thanks again! I didn'T want to hassle with this, because I work mostly from home where I must run Windows. On the other hand, I have saved these snippets. I didn't know PHP is capable of this, I learn something new every day :)

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen see custom_proc_nice() function from the documentation to deal with caveat 2 and 3.

Comment: proc_nice only works with Windows. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-nice.php

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ilmari Karonen's answer:

If you want to increase or decrease the niceness of the current process use `renice` together with the current process id:

```
function custom_proc_nice($priority) {

  exec("renice +$priority ".getmypid());

}
```

If you want to prevent the niceness to persist after the PHP process exits you will need a shutdown function:

```
function exit_func(){

  // Restore priority
  proc_nice(0);
}

register_shutdown_function('exit_func');
```

**Resources**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-nice.php

Comment: Alas, unless you're running PHP as the root user (which is terribly unsafe, so you really shouldn't be), [`renice` cannot decrease the niceness of a process, either.](http://linux.die.net/man/8/renice)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the information and reactivity Ilmari ! Is the default value for a php process set to 0?