# How do I make a difficult php script (cronjob) run for a longer time to not kill the server?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, cron

I have a PHP cronjob which runs at 6:00am every day to do some calculations and store them in the SQL. What happens now is that the site becomes a bit unresponsive for about 40 seconds while the cron is running.

I was wondering whether using `sleep()` in the script would do the trick? Let's say I'd pause it for 2 seconds roughly every second. Therefore, the script would run for a lot longer time, but would also let apache use the system's resources.

Am I right? Does it work? Or will the script still keep resources to itself, even during the `sleep()`?

Comment: My first instinct is to lower your CPU usage, since I assume that you are CPU bound. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247816/limit-cpu-load-or-set-process-prority

Comment: What kind of calculations is the job suppose to do?